# Forward Kinematics Skeleton Programming

Tags: animation, maya, kinematics

I am putting together a project where I need to be able to source outside data as a means of inputting skeleton joint positions into Maya. Basically I have a spreadsheet of sequential joint positions for the skeleton which I would like to load into Maya and then link to the skin. Does anyone know a way to upload or reference these positions (as FK into Maya)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to convert your spreadsheet data to [atom format](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-C70392B3-7FD2-4C1F-A3BE-CE0A82D02F91-htm.html)

Atom is a [json based format](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-9FA7198C-6BC9-4CB7-AA86-74C3C0A47576-htm.html) for exchanging animation data and, since its JSON based you should be able to concoct a CSV to ATOM translator using Python's built in `csv` and `json` modules.